# asp.net core web application dropdownlist

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

i want to implement a dropdown list,don't know how to go about it.i want to populate employee FullName on the dropdown.Thanks
Note:i'm using asp.net core razor page not mvc..

```
//Employee model
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }           
    }
```

Comment: You should have a look at the Select Tag Helper: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper.  The examples there show the data being generated in the page handler methods. You should be able to adapt them to your chosen data access technology.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/search?view=aspnetcore-2.1) explain how.

Comment: @CodeNotFound thank you for reaching out, i got an error "could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type DbSet<Employee>. select not found". Any help to go about this!!